# Can you specify &type parameters for iframe in CSS?

Tags: css, iframe

Is it possible to specify `&paramters=whatever` type stuff for `<iframe>` in CSS?

I want to embed multi-track audio from archive.org. So for example, something like this:

```html
<iframe src="https://archive.org/embed/art_of_war_librivox​&playlist=1​&list_height=200" width="100%" height="200"></iframe>
```

These bits are easy to do in CSS

```css
.multitrack iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

But what about `​&playlist=1​&list_height=200`? Does that *have* to be done in HTML every time? I want to get it down to just:

```html
<div class="multitrack">
<iframe src="https://archive.org/embed/art_of_war_librivox"></iframe>
</div>
```

I want to embed it on AO3.org, which is extremely stringent about what we're allowed to use. So please no *"use this entirely other tool to solve your problem!"* this time. If I can't do it with CSS, I'm pretty sure I can't do it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a CSS based solution to your problem.

Your `&playlist=1​&list_height=200` is telling the iframed site iself (via GET request) that you want the first playlist and a playlist height of 200px to be rendered.

Comment: Thanks for an clear, unambiguous answer. Now I can stop wasting my time trying to make it happen :)